# funtion wont print enter forloop referencing an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I somehow can't get my for loop inside of a function to print elements in an array.
could someone point out why javascript is not allowing the iteration to occur and only printing the first element?

```js
const data1 = [17, 21, 23];

function printForecast(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let dayVsDays = i <= 1 ? 'day' : 'days'
    return `The temp is ${array[i]}ºC in ${[i+1]} ${dayVsDays}`;
  }
}

console.log(printForecast(data1))
```

Comment: That return will shortcut the loop so it will quit the function after the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use return inside a loop unless you want to return the result of an specific iteration; this is why you only get the first iteration.